# Scalability of numChildren() function in Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I borrowed some code from the great firebase/friendlypix-web repo (https://github.com/firebase/friendlypix-web/blob/39cca671242d833e83252e31f30ed9b655f9478b/src/FirebaseHelper.js#L722).

The snippet makes use of the `numChildren()` function to count a user's followers. However, a comment above the code warns that "This won't scale if a user has a huge amount of followers."

It's hard to judge what is meant here by "huge".

A fix for this could be a cloud function to increment a counter, but it would be nice to know when that would be really necessary, as I might never reach a number considered "huge" by the Google staff who wrote that comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit is not as much Firebase itself, but reality of device bandwidth and the economics of reading data.

The main thing to realize is that `numChildren()` is a client-side operation that counts the number of child nodes in the `DataSnapshot`.

If I recall correctly, the `followers` node of FriendlyPix has a structure like this:

```
"followers": {
  "uidOfUser1ButThenOfALength": true,
  "uidOfUser2ButThenOfALength": true,
  "uidOfUser3ButThenOfALength": true,
  "uidOfUser4ButThenOfALength": true
}
```

If you download this structure, you're reading 150 or so bytes. Nothing too bad, but if all you need is the number of children, you could also get that result by reading a structure like this:

```
"followerCount": 4
```

And this is only 20 bytes, saving the user 130 of bandwidth, and you 130 of billed reads for each user.

As your app gets more users, and each user likely gains more followers, these numbers start to add up. With an average of 20 followers, reading all data to call `numChildren()` client-side takes up 672 bytes, while reading a counter will only take 21 bytes.

Comment: Thanks for this important information. Didn't realise that the entire structure gets downloaded. So it makes sense to immediately set up a cloud function. There's some good example code in friendlypix-web/functions/sendFollowerNotification.js to help with that.